# Passing a property to a method for read/write

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would like to know how to pass a property to a method.

Currently, this is my method:

```
public static string Pick(this IFilePicker openFileService, Func<string> getCurrentFolder, Action<string> setCurrentFolder)
```

I use it to pick files (with a dialog). It automatically sets the current folder of the `OpenFileDialog` calling the `getCurrentFolder` `Func`. If the user correctly selects a file, then, the `setCurrentFolder` action is called.

I'm using it like this:

```
Pick(openFileService, () => Settings.Current.Folder, str => Settings.Current.Folder = str);
```

But it looks cumbersome to me. Why use 2 parameters instead 1? I could just pass the property.

But how?

I would like to call it like this:

```
Pick<Settings>(openFileService, x => x.Current.Folder);
```

Is that even possible?

NOTE Settings.Current is a Singleton. It's autogenerated.

Comment: It is possible when using an `Expression<>`, but you'll then have to "read" / evaluate that expression to get the actual `PropertyInfo` of the property to get/set, so you can then use reflection to get/set the value.

Comment: @bassfader I know what you mean, but how? :(

Comment: Your two lambda expressions are currently different - did you mean `Settings.Current.Folder` or `Settings.CurrentFolder`?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. It's Settings.Current.Folder

Comment: A property is nothing but a package of two methods, a get- and a set-method. So by providing a property within a delegate, you reference either the one or the other. Thats why you can´t read **and** write the properties value within the delegate.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no clean way of doing this. The code you've got is the simplest approach, I believe.

You *could* change the method to accept an `Expression<Func<string>>` instead, then examine the expression tree to get the property... but it would be a lot of effort, be less efficient, and give you less compile-time checking. You'd still need to pass `() => Settings.Current.Folder` - it would only remove the need for the final parameter.

To be specific, in your case you'd need to build an expression tree that still accessed the getter for `Settings.Current`, but then the setter for `Folder`. You'd then need to compile both expression trees.

It's all feasible, but it's a lot of fiddly work. Your current approach is clunky but simple. Unless you need to do this a *huge* amount, I'd just accept the clunkiness.

Assuming `Settings.Current` doesn't change, the other option would be to pass in the *name* of the property, so you'd call it with:

```
Pick(openFileService, Settings.Current, nameof(Settings.Folder));
```

That would still require reflection and would be somewhat error-prone, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

A property is nothing but a package of two methods, a get- and a set-method. So by providing a property within a delegate, you reference either the one or the other. Thats why you can´t read **and** write the properties value within the delegate.

In order to **read** a property you surely need some method that **returns** a `string` and **expects** nothing (namely a `Func<string>`). When you want to **set** a property, you´ll need something that **excepts** a string. but doesn´t **return** anything (an `Action<string>`).

Furthermore, let´s see how the delegate *could* be defined:

```
Pick(string file, Delegate readAndWriteDelegate)
{
    // what can you do with the delegate? You don´t know if you can provide a string or if it returns one
    // do I have to use this?
    readAndWriteDelegate(file);
    // or this?
    var result = readAndWriteDelegate();
    // or even this?
    var result = readAndWriteDelegate(file);
    // in fact I could even use this
    MyClass m = readAndWriteDelegate(3);
}
```

I just used the existing `Delegate` to show there´s no way to even *declare* your delegate and provide its type-safety.

Leaving asside that the code above won´t even compile as we´d have to call `Invoke` on the `Delegate`, you see it´s completely unclear what your delegate actually expects and what it returns. Even if we could determine it´s some kind of a `string`delegate, it´s unclear if the delegate should return a string or expect one or even do both and thus how we can *call* it.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested just returning the path, but actually `Pick()` method needs to return the *file* as well as setting the path.

I'd add an overload or new method to the `OpenFileService` which will read/set the Path in the Settings.Current object, so the calls don't have to care where the 'current' path comes from.  I'm assuming that 90+ % of the time you'll always read `Settings.Current.Path` and Write back to `Settings.Current.Path` so it's probably best to make the `OpenFileService` handle this, rather than every call to it?

Comment: I think I've not explained myself well. The method returns a path to a file (string), but in the Dialog box it shows, an initial directory will be shown. This directory is stored using a Settings class. First, it's retrieved, and if the user selects a file and accepts the dialog, the folder that contains the file is saved. That's why I need the 2 parameters. One to load the InitialFolder and the other to save it (on success).

Comment: @SuperJMN No problem ;)